# Is Google Places API available via maps.google.cn domain?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, great-firewall-of-china

is Google places API available via maps.google.cn domain?
This works from China.

`curl "https://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA"`

but this results in 404
`The requested URL /maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=SOME_QUERY&types=locality was not found on this server. That’s all we know.`

tried with http:// but no luck.

Thanks!

(keys are removed from the examples above)

Comment: Done! And you're welcome, happy to clarify this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not available, and if you're in China, please note that this is a prohibited territory as per https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories/