# Angular 8: Google Maps API Support for China

Tags: angular, google-maps

We are using Google maps in our Angular 8 application. Since Google maps is not supported in China.
How to check if the customer is from China? If it is from China how to use google.cn map API in our application

Comment: you can check the user country on basis of user IP address and then change your map API key on the basis of the country.

Comment: google.cn shall not be used for Maps APIs either. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782279/is-google-places-api-available-via-maps-google-cn-domain