# Can't enable Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have enabled the Billing account in Google console for android project. But I am getting the error while enabling the Places API. The error is "Billing account cannot pay for Maps in your region".

Comment: Refer this : https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues - Billing Status Failed

Comment: What country is your billing account based in? If it's India, please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027297/11742502 and if it's a prohibited territory such as China, Iran, Vietnam... check this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819360/11742502